# Power Query: UDF, change the data type of the result

Tags: function, type-conversion, powerquery

I'm doing my very first steps in Power Query UDFs.
My goal is the function result like (Excel) DATE (). This is how I reach the goal:

```
() => Date.From (DateTime.LocalNow ())
```

The result is correct, but the data type is "any". I want the data type to be Date instantly. How can I integrate this into the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type to be a date like this:

```
() as date => Date.From (DateTime.LocalNow ())
```

The whole query will look like this:

```
let
    Source = () as date => Date.From (DateTime.LocalNow ())
in
    Source
```

---

If you had a parameter, you can specify its type as well. For example,

```
let  
    AddOne = (x as number) as number => x + 1
in  
    AddOne
```